Can I know synchronously if an AsyncIterator is at its end?
I have an async iterator. While iterating over its element, I would like to know if I am reading the last element. Is this possible?
async def start_stream():
    idx = 0
    while idx < 100:
        yield idx
        idx += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(0.01)

stream = start_stream()
async for i in stream:
    if stream.has_next():
        handle(i, is_over=True)
    else:
        handle(i, is_over=False)


Not in general. The iterator itself may not know, if it's returning data from an external source.

The only way the iterator could know is if it always reads ahead to the next element before returning the current element.

You can implement this behavior yourself if you need it, and if the logic of your iterator allows it.  See https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter for details.
